# limit of a polynomial over a $\log$ exponential

Tags: real-analysis, limits, exponential-function

I want to know the limit of

$$\frac{n^{\frac{1}{k}}}{(8c)^{\frac{\log n}{\log \log n}}}$$

as $n \to \infty$ for some constants $k > 1$, $c > 1$.

I conjecture (based on numerical calculations) that this limit should be infinity, but I am not sure how to prove it. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint : write everything in an exponential as
$$u_n=\exp\left[\ln n\left(\frac1k-\frac{\ln(8c)}{\ln\ln n}\right)\right].$$
The answer should be straightforward from this point.

Comment: Thanks! To clarify, the steps from here are: as n approaches infinity, the term in parenthesis approaches 1/k, and ln(n) approaches infinity, so e^(infinity * 1/k) = infinity (roughly speaking)?

Comment: "Roughly speaking" is not a mathematical expression, I'd rather say that you have sketched the end of the proof. I think that you should now work on a rigorous writing.